# Can Reporting Services 2008 be installed on an existing web farm?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, iis, ssrs

I have a question regarding whether Reporting Services can be installed on an existing web farm, at least the front end portion.

The situation is that we have a limited number of servers available to work with (4).  We currently have two web farms of two servers each.  One farm runs our staging and UAT sites that need to be exposed to the outside, and the other runs out QA and internal dev sites.  We would like to setup two separate Reporting Server instances to support each of these two web farms, but I don't have any more servers to run it on.

What I would like to do is to install Reporting Services on each of the servers within each farm, with only two back-end SSRS databases.  So each farm would essentially use a single Report Server 'instance'.

I've installed SSRS on a server that was already running IIS and serving up sites before, but I'm not sure if it will work in this situation.  I don't need to get into details of how to configure it at this point, just whether it is a viable option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can install SQL Server reporting Services with in same server but you need more RAM because reporting services take more memory when rendering large reports.
Before we have same setup in my environment but its hitting my performance like blocking then 
we increased RAM.

Simply I am saying its viable when your server is capable to take more load.